# PHP Data- URI to Image

Tags: php, javascript, canvas

I have Data URI(image) and  I am trying to save using php, my code is

```
$filename = 'test.png';
$fp = fopen("user_images/".$filename,"w");
fwrite($fp, base64_decode($_POST['strDataURI']));
fclose($fp);
```

It gives me corrupted image always, But i am getting right image when i use in **Javascript**

```
document.write('<img src="'+strDataURI+'"/>');
```

Comment: What is `$_POST['strDataURI']`?

Comment: $_POST['strDataURI'] is

Comment: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAEvklEQVR4nO3BAQ0AAADCoPdPbQ43oAAAA

Comment: (I'd probably just try this: `fwrite($fp, file_get_contents($_POST['strDataURI']);`; think it should work in recent versions of PHP, which can handle data URIs without the double-slash.)

Comment: because data uris have a prefix with the mime type ,you need to remove it before decoding the base 64 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I believe PHP now supports (>5.4.17 ) "proper" data URIs (i.e. without the double-slash necessary in older versions) I'd probably just try this:

```
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents($_POST['strDataURI']);
```

...seems to work okay in PHP 5.4.17 using a test script I just wrote using a data uri generated [from this online tool](http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/).